# Dask read_csv collapses columns while pandas read_csv don't

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dask

I'm having trouble reading a dask dataframe from multiple CSV files. I was able to read into dask dataframe but the result doesn't seem what I expect. The result collapses all the columns into a single column.

My csv files are around 20gb each and was saved in utf-8 format. It was originally generated by using pandas to_csv function(with encoding = 'utf-8-sig').

I thought the main source of the problem is from the dataset I have, but unfortunately, I'm not sure how to make a reproducible example here. I hope the illustration below may help you see where the problem is.

I read dask dataframe with below code.

```
dfs_all = dd.read_csv('data/*.csv',
                        engine='python',
                        encoding='utf-8',
                        error_bad_lines=False,
                        )
```

I had to specify engine, encoding, error_bad_lines or it generates errors. 
Without engine='python', it generates

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 1005
```

W/O encoding it generates

```
UnicodeDecodeErtor: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 3051: character maps to <undefined>
```

w/o error_bad_lines=False it shows

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: unexpected end of data
```

Above dfs_all result says

```
Skipping line 1006: unexpected end of data
```

but it still works. However, the result seems to have collapsed all the columns into a single column.

```
dfs_all.shape
Out[4]: (Delayed('int-b880bc37-e65a-489b-b71c-314ec76f87a2'), 1)
```

I tested with a single csv file with pandas read_csv and it works alright.

```
df_pandas = pd.read_csv('data/outfile_09.csv', nrows=100) 
# it works without specification above
df_pandas.shape()
Out[10]: (100, 9) # 9 columns
```

I tested if dask still has problem reading the file so I tested as below, and dask read pandas without trouble.

```
dd.from_pandas(df_pandas, chunksize=50).shape
Out[14]: (Delayed('int-0e7ac94b-c571-4204-a0fb-351d38a50130'), 9)
```

I'm confused about where the problem is. Any piece of advice is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Found the reason: it was because of the encoding. While it was encoded 'utf-8-sig' when it is written, but I used 'utf-8' when reading. While Pandas was able to configure this, dask needed clarification. Hope it may help someone.